# A Better Way to Edit Tumblr Blogs in HTML?

Tags: html, editor, blogs, tumblr

I'm writing blogs on Tumblr using HTML (I use HTML in order to control the content of my blogs flexibly and precisely) and I'm coding with Tumblr's own HTML editor, which is not so bad and I can continue writing in this way. However, there're some points I don't like, e.g.:

- I can't adjust the width of the editor window and so the view looks a little compact.
- After posting (or saving as draft), the source code will be automatically rearranged, pretty differently from my original version. That includes the line breaks, automatic adding of HTML tags (like `</p>`), and converting of special characters, like `>` to `&gt;` and `&emsp;` to   (displayed as a dot).

My ideal wish is that I can use my own editor (namely Visual Studio Code) to manage my blogs. I could get a more familiar and comfortable working environment, together with useful functions like auto-complete. But there's still a conflict here - Very often I need to use the "Preview on Blog" feature (so that I can check the actual result).

To explain the situation, I describe an odd plan as example here. I could edit the source code using VS Code, during this I copy everything to Tumblr's editor when I need to "Preview on Blog", until posting. And whenever I need to update blogs I do the same work. That is, to keep a synchronous update of my blogs as local HTML files and online on Tumblr. But this way is not pretty convenient.

Is there a magical way to achieve a connection between the local editor and the website? Or, in general, how can I get a more comfortable workspace to write blogs on Tumblr using HTML?

Thanks a lot!

---

EDIT:
I'm not blogging on Tumblr anymore, I started to set up my own blogging platform using [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) and [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/).

(BTW, the code editor I use has changed from Visual Studio Code to NeoVim.)

Comment: Hey. AFAIK you can only update the tumblr template by pasting the code into their editor. I have never run it myself but I think at some point there was a way to run a local instance of tumblr so you could change your template in realtime and test it. I cannot find that that tech exists anymore. If you wanted version control for your template you would need a git repo (or svn). Tumblr also has a theme recovery url https://www.tumblr.com/themes/recover I assume you will only get so much history with that. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9116171/1238244 which advises creating a test copy

Comment: (Test copy is something I prefer but i also have local copies of all the tumblr templates I have worked on and developed)

Comment: Oh wow, this is huge if true: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19608372/1238244

Comment: @lharby Thanks for your reply, but what I want to locally deal with are the HTML files of the blogs, not the theme (in fact before I found the thread that you mentioned). Or are the two problems actually talking about the same thing?

Comment: Hmm, maybe the tumblr theming using handlebar style markup to inject backend code and params like `{Post} {/Post}` etc. That won't render in normal browser. I think you would have to copy all of the code from the browser page and stick that somewhere but that is even more detached from your source code than editing a template.

Comment: Hey Lutalli, could you find any good way to maintain your posts? I really wonder why it's every time automatically rearranged, it's really annoying.

Comment: @AntonioVal Thanks for the reply. To tell the truth though: I'm planning to migrate my blogs to my own website built via GitHub Pages with Jekyll (not done yet due to my laziness). There I'm able to manage and edit the blogs, configurations, etc. way more easily and directly (using my own code editor); also I can design my own CSS for the whole site. It requires a little bit more work, but when it's done everything will be mega cool. I don't know which requirements your blogs have but GitHub Pages (or, in general, setting up your own website) could be a consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer and the recommendation! Will look into GitHub Pages.